# Merging many pickle Dataframes into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 600 Dataframes saved and stored as .pickle and I'd like to merge (or rather append) them into one DataFrame. The total size of them is 10GB.

When I read each of them and append them into one big DataFrame and then save the full version to dist the entire process takes 2 hours on 16GB machine.

I think it takes a lot of time because each time I append a new DataFrame system allocates new memory space for the entire new DataFrame?

How can I do this faster?

Comment: Have you tried pd concat and passing the full list?

Comment: Do you need one dataframe or just one pickle file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than append them one by one, I suggest you use `pd.concat()` and pass all the dataframes in a go.

```
Output = pd.concat([pd.read_pickle(r'location/'+x) for x in os.listdir('location')])
```

We can create the list of dataframes using list comprehensions, supposed this pickle files are saved in the same folder, and use `pd.concat` to concatenate them all in a single dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

A small improvement on the accepted answer is to use a generator expression inside `concat`:

```py
from pandas import read_pickle, concat

df = concat(read_pickle(f) for f in list_of_files)
```

By removing the list comprehension `[...]`, we reduce the memory footprint of the operation, since there is no need to hold all of the results from list comprehension in memory at once.

Note that the `list_of_files` variable should contain the list of files, e.g. globbed using `pathlib`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

list_of_files = Path('.').glob('*.pickle')
```